# Automapper - Mapping subclasses

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a method that defines some mappings as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Mapping definitions for domain entities to database entities
/// </summary>
private static void DefineMappingDomainEntitiesToDatabase()
{
    // SellerListing 
    Mapper.CreateMap<SellerListing, Data.SellerListing>();

    // ListingShippingCost
    Mapper.CreateMap<ListingShippingCost, Data.ListingShippingCost>();
}
```

The SellerListing entity definition contains the following property

```
List<ListingShippingCost> ListingShippingCostList { get; set; }
```

When I call `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` I get the following error:

```
SellerListing -> SellerListing (Destination member list)
MyApp.Entities.SellerListing -> MyApp.Data.SellerListing (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
ListingShippingCost
```

So it's telling me that I don't have a mapping for ListingShippingCost, even though I do have a mapping definition for ListingShippingCost, as you can see. Apparently I need to add something to my SellerListing defintion for this mapping, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define from where are you mapping the **ListingShippingCost** property:

```
private static void DefineMappingDomainEntitiesToDatabase()
{
    // SellerListing 
    Mapper.CreateMap<SellerListing, Data.SellerListing>()
          .ForMember(x => x.ListingShippingCost, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(y => y.ListingShippingCostList));

    // ListingShippingCost
    Mapper.CreateMap<ListingShippingCost, Data.ListingShippingCost>();
}
```